# Drop onto a control created at runtime

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I have a self created calendar program that I am having issues with.  I am adding a select range option which relies on a drag event to select a range.

If I create two labels in the designer I can drag data from one to another with no problem. The issue I have is that I cannot drag onto a control I have created at runtime. I can drag from one but not to one.

```
Private Sub SetupMonths()
    Dim dayNo As Integer

    For monthNo As Integer = 0 To 11
        grpMonth(monthNo) = New GroupBox
        grpMonth(monthNo).Text = MonthName(monthNo + 1)
        Me.pnlCalendar.Controls.Add(grpMonth(monthNo))
        For dayY = 0 To 4
            For dayX = 0 To 6
                dayNo = dayX + dayY * 7
                lblDay(monthNo, dayNo) = New Label
                lblDay(monthNo, dayNo).Font = Me.lblDayFont.Font
                lblDay(monthNo, dayNo).Text = dayNo
                lblDay(monthNo, dayNo).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                grpMonth(monthNo).Controls.Add(lblDay(monthNo, dayNo))

                AddHandler lblDay(monthNo, dayNo).MouseDown, AddressOf DayDrag
                AddHandler lblDay(monthNo, dayNo).DragOver, AddressOf DayOver
                AddHandler lblDay(monthNo, dayNo).DragDrop, AddressOf DayDrop

            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub DayDrag(ByVal sender As Label, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("Start draging " & dayDragFrom)
    sender.DoDragDrop(sender.Tag, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    Debug.WriteLine("End")
End Sub
Private Sub DayOver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("Over")
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub DayDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("Drop")
    ' More code will go here
End Sub
```

The "DayDrag" handler is adding fine, and is triggering ok.  I can drag from one of these to a control created in the designer. However the "Day Over" and "Day Drop" handlers don't seem to be attaching, and as such I cannot drag onto them.

Open to any suggestion,

Many Thanks.

Mat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be better as a comment but I don't have enough rep.

Have you tried setting the AllowDrop property to True?

```
lblDay(monthNo, dayNo) = New Label
lblDay(monthNo, dayNo).AllowDrop = True
...
```

It flags whether a control can accept data dragged onto it, so if it's false this may be why your mouse handler works but your drag handlers don't.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.allowdrop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984430%28v=vs.71%29.aspx